# Should questions about pronunciation specify which English dialect the OP is interested in?

Tags: discussion, pronunciation

In a question asking for the pronunciation of a word, should the question make clear to which English dialect it is referring?

If the word is pronounced differently in American English and British English, which answer should be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer should report how it is pronounced in all dialects. However, in most cases, only one pronunciation need be given (using a multidialect transcription system).